# Handle UIView as UINavigation bar

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, xcode9, iphone-x

All,

In our application, we are hiding Navigation Bar and Used a UIView Instead of default navigation bar, It is working well in all devices expect in iPhone X, The UIview is cutting, How to handle it? What needs to be used

Comment: Have you set it up with storyboard or code? Please show it.

Comment: Below link might be useful to you https://medium.com/@kahseng.lee123/creating-custom-navigation-bar-tab-bar-for-iphone-x-f03b1e1827d3

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow but in general on iphoneX you have to take into account a **UIView's safeArea** :)